# use jquery append a string to DOM then use jquery selector cannot find it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append a HTML String to DOM

```
var str = "<input time=\"y\" name=\"changeDate\" type=\"text\"  class=\"input_M3_1\" id=\"textfield2\"  value='' dataType=\"Sino\"  >";
```

then append to dom and give a value;

```
$('#datadiv').append(str);
$("input[name='changeDate']").val('2014-8-15');
```

After this,I Use jquery selector

```
var date='2014-8-15';
$("input[value="+date+"][name='changeDate']");
```

Use the selector I just cannot find the it,And also I see it had add a new attribute name "realvalue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val` modifies the `value` property of the element not it's `value` attribute. For understanding the difference between attributes and properties you can check this question: [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

You can filter the inputs that have specific value property using `filter` method:

```
$("input[name='changeDate']").filter(function() {
    return this.value === date;
});
```